# An illegal choice has been detected when I submit my webform module

Tags: webforms

I am getting this error

> An illegal choice has been detected

when I am submitting my webform and that is happening only on the select fields , as i read on the internet it suppose to have default value but i don't know how to put it in the code I am editing my webform-form-16.tpl and I have the code like this.

```
$form['submitted']['material']['#title']='';
$form['submitted']['material']['#prefix']='<div class="row"><label>Material:</label><br><span class="select" id="selectselect">&nbsp;</span>';
$form['submitted']['material']['#options'] = array('Steel'=>'Steel','Yellow Gold'=>'Yellow Gold','White Gold'=>'White Gold','Steel and Yellow Gold'=>'Steel and Yellow Gold');
$form['submitted']['material']['#suffix']='</div>';
```

Comment: This isn't the right way to create a select element using the forms api. You should be setting `'#type' => 'select'` rather than using #prefix and #suffix. If you need to customize the HTML you then need to override the theming of the element.

Comment: I have a webform created in admin with type textfield and type select and here i am custumoizain but i am getting error An illegal choice has been detected

Comment: You can't customize it like that. It'll break it, as you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

Editing webform-form-**.tpl or any template file is designed to alter the theme or display of the webform. It seems you are having issue with the forms content, specifically default values.

If you are using the Form API to create your form in your own module, you will need to declare it as described in the FAPI documentation.

```
<?php
  $form['selected'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Selected'),
    '#options' => array(
      0 => t('No'),
      1 => t('Yes'),
    ),
    '#default_value' => $category['selected'],
    '#description' => t('Set this to <em>Yes</em> if you would like this category to be selected by default.'),
  );
?>
```

The error that you are getting tends to occur when form elements are submitted that were not defined in the original form. And by the look of your template edit, that could easily be the case.

Check out your log at Administer > Logs > Recent log entries to see what is causing the error.

To get an empty entry submitted from the select options force the 'empty option' form declaration. Works like a treat.

```
'#empty_option'=>t('- Select -'),
```

Good luck.
xK

Comment: My problem was not exactly as mentioned in reply but `Administer > Logs > Recent log entries` helped me.

Answer (score 0):

You say you're using "webform" but you have a FAPI select box. If you're making webforms using the [Webform](http://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module -- then the correct approach is to create a custom webform Component in a custom module. [Here is an example implementation from a blog from the internet](http://szilagyi-andras.com/info/custom-webform-component-options).

From the blog post:

```
/**
* Private implementation of hook_webform_select_options_info().
*
* @see webform_webform_select_options_info()
*/
function general_webform_select_options_info()
{
  $items = array();

  $items['people'] = array(
    'title' => t('People'),
    'options callback' => 'general_people_options'
  );

  return $items;
}
/**
* Option list containing the site users
*/
function general_people_options()
{
$q = db_query("SELECT `name`
                FROM {users}
                WHERE 1
                ORDER BY `name` ASC
               ");

$options = array();

while ($r = db_fetch_object($q))
{
  $options[$r -> name] = $r -> name;
}// WHILE

return $options;
}
```

Comment: I didn't mange to do it u are right but i don't understand good

Comment: where should i modify